# I want to get the values ​of id and pw using axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to send id and pw in post format from [http://127.0.0.1:8080/login'](http://127.0.0.1:8080/login%27) to 'http://127.0.0.1:8085/login' using axios.

But I'm not getting it. js problem, what is it?
bootstrap 사용했고요.

I used bootstrap.

It may be right to get the input id and pw value with 'getElemenbyId'..

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>login</title>
    <style>
        .form-floating mb-3{
            max-width: 500px;
        }
        .form-floating{
            max-width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
    <h1 style="margin-top: 150px; margin-bottom: 20px;">login</h1>

    <form>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="id">
        <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" name="pw">
        <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>

        <input style="margin-top: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="로그인">
    </form>
    </center>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- vue / axios -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      id = document.getElementById("floatingInput")
      pw = document.getElementById("floatingPassword")

      let frm = new FormData();  
      frm.append('id', id)
      frm.append('pw', pw)
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8085/login', null,frm)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log('failed',error)
        })
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your script inside a submit handler, something like:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  id = document.getElementById("floatingInput")
  ...
  axios.post('http://...');
});
```